# Linux ubuntu 14.04: youtube only plays videos when mouse is moving

Tags: flash, ubuntu, video, youtube

I have had this problem for a while now:  When I watch a youtube video (or anything flash-related it seems) the video will at some point get 'stuck' and the only way to make it continue is to move my cursor or type something.  After trying a gazillion different versions of adobe flash plugins for mozilla firefox (oh yeah, I tried chrome too!) and changing settings and what-not... here is a really simple fix:

go to the terminal and type:

$  while true; do greg; done

my name is greg :)

This creates an infinite loop and for whatever reason the effort of that infinite loop makes the computer keep adobe flash playing videos without getting stuck.  I looked at the resource monitor and it only takes up 350kb of ram, and no cpu.

I know this is a stupid hack... but honestly, it works and spending your time downloading new and old versions of adobe flash sucks